# how to test for storage leaks in pallets

Tags: pallet, storage, testing

Storage leaks in runtimes can be very damaging and cleaning up with a runtime update migration is non-trivial. I'd like to ensure the absence of storage leaks already in unit testing.

My strategy would be:

1. measure size of TestExternalities
2. execute a few dispatchables
3. call a cleanup dispatchable that is supposed to purge all storage that has been created by the last step
4. measure size of TestExternalities again and compare

How can I measure state size before and after a unit test?

Would it even be possible to get a diff, such that debugging is more comfortable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`StorageNoopGuard`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/storage_noop_guard/struct.StorageNoopGuard.html) to assert that your storage changes sum up to a No-OP.
This does the same as [`assert_storage_noop!`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/macro.assert_storage_noop.html) but for a code block. It is not measuring the state size, but comparing the root hash of the Trie. This exactly tells us whether something changed.
As example:

```rust
#[test]
fn cleanup_works() {
    use frame_support::{StorageNoopGuard, storage::unhashed::*};

    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        let _guard = StorageNoopGuard::default();
        
        // Here you are modifying the storage.
        put(b"key", b"value");
        // And here is the cleanup - which you did not forget ;)
        kill(b"key");
        // The guard will not panic because the state did not change since its construction.
    });
}
```

It works by calculating the storage root has in the beginning with `storage_root(StateVersion::V1)` and then again in the end. The state did not change iff they are equal.
You can change the key in `kill` to `b"key1"` to simulate an error and see it fail with:

```
thread 'tests::cleanup_works' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `[124, 55, 174, 141, 90, 56, 20, 107, 57, 116, 85, 28, 128, 109, 139, 53, 156, 61, 56, 117, 109, 227, 115, 247, 235, 180, 147, 215, 81, 174, 223, 144]`,
 right: `[235, 68, 37, 78, 47, 204, 154, 99, 92, 28, 105, 55, 55, 229, 121, 115, 249, 23, 80, 192, 245, 244, 195, 146, 103, 68, 36, 175, 217, 246, 86, 194]`:
StorageNoopGuard detected wrongful storage changes.'
```

I don't think there is a nice state-differ available in FRAME. But it could be done, by storing all keys and traversing the tree and following the differing keys.

PS: I think these stale-state errors happen the easiest when the pallet is refactored, not when it is originally created. Anyway, probably better than not doing it.

Comment: this is really useful, thank you. However: what we want to know in order to detect storage leaks is: "Are there any NEW KEYS in the storage". We don't care about keys that changed their VALUE. So, our test may not qualify as a noop, even if there is no storage leak. In many cases, however, we may be able to use your solution by just manually reversing known storage changes

Comment: Ahh okay. Yea this is not possible without inventing new storage guard types. If you have the need for some generic cleanup you could do it in the `new_test_ext` and then check for NO-OP afterwards. But I see what you mean. Could be that is fairly simple to hook into the storage overlay. I will think about it.